Is there a good method to recover the original functions from their convolution?
Occasionally, I failed to detect the function which is just the convolution of two simple functions. For instance
$$
2a\sin{at}*\sin{at}=\sin{at}-at\cos{at}
$$
One possible way is to observe the original functions by its inverse Lalapce transform for
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[\sin{at}-at\cos{at}\right]=\frac{2a^3}{(s^2+a^2)^2}
$$
which gives the indication of convolution of $\sin{at}$ due to the fact $\mathcal{L}\left[\sin{at}\right]=\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$.
This is an easy example. Is there any generic method to reverse the convolution? For example, how can I figure out $t^2$ and $e^{-|t|}$ from $2(s^2+2)$?
Ps. I have searched such topic but no substantial help can be found. In addition, I might expect the method can recover the unique solution.

Just consider ways of writing your function's Laplace transform as a product of Laplace transforms.  There is no uniqueness.

You will see a lot of algorithms to deconvolve. But they are not analytical methods - mostly engineering solutions for recovering images from noisy images and similar such. Also the functions are not unique. I have not come across general deconvolution techniques in mathematics that don't end up in unsolvable looking integrals

The answer of JeanMarie here shows that no such method is possible in general. For instance, the pair $t^3/3, -\text{sgn}(t)e^{-|t|}$ also convolves to $2(s^2+2)$.
